# Rejected Facebook Built-in Like Action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to submitting built-in like action.

First time, I used a button on my site labeled with 'like' and without any logo and linked it to the action, but I've got the following feedback:

> Your Like or Recommend button branding conflicts with Section 5.6 of
>   the Facebook Terms and Section I.8 of the Platform Policy
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/branding/).
>   Please resubmit with a different graphic that reflects your own
>   branding and the ux of your site.

Then I change the button text to 'Useful?', but I've go the following feedback:

> Your action conflicts with section IV.3 of the Platform Policies
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/). You must make it clear to
>   the user that you will be publishing a story to facebook and get their
>   permission before actually publishing the story. Additionally, your
>   action must not be confusing or misleading and should accurately
>   represent the action the user took within your app.

This confusing, I'm not sure what the problem is, please help :)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need a graphic that reflects your own branding, but you must also make it clear to the user that you will be publishing a story to Facebook before you do so.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thank you for your feedback, but can you explain more about making it clear to the user that it will be published on Facebook.
And if I just used any graphic without text, will this problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all explained near the bottom of the the [Facebook branding page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/branding/). On your first attempt you used 'like' and that is not allowed on your custom button. The second time you used 'Useful?' and that is not clear enough and is confusing.

I suggest you read the branding policy examples and the other material.

[Section 5.6 of the Facebook Terms](http://www.facebook.com/legal/terms)

> You will not use our copyrights or trademarks (including Facebook, the Facebook and F Logos, FB, Face, Poke, Book and Wall), or any confusingly similar marks, except as expressly permitted by our Brand Usage Guidelines or with our prior written permission.

[Section I.8 of the Platform Policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/)

> You must not use or make derivative use of Facebook icons, or use terms for Facebook features and functionality, if such use could confuse users into thinking that the reference is to Facebook features or functionality.

Section IV.3

> If a user grants you a publishing permission, actions you take on the user's behalf must be expected by the user and consistent with the user's actions within your app.